# What happened to *kweþana?

Tags: semantics, frequency

In a time when distinct Germanic dialects already existet in geographically diffenrent areas, the usual verbs to signal a following direct speech seem to be descendant of PrG „*kweþana“ in any dialect (e.g. Go: Wulfila, OS: Heliand, OHG: Monsee Fragments).
However in todays‘ use of Germanic languages (both oral and written) forms like G „sagen“, EN „to say“ Du „zeggen“, IS „segja“, Sw „säga“, Nw „seie“, Da „sige“ dominate.

Why and how did this often used verb nearly completely diappear form all Germanic languages? Why and how could it consequently be replaced be the „same“ word in distinct dialects over geographically diffenrent areas?

Comment: LIke most "why" questions, the only answer that can confidently be given is "because it did". But I will suggest that it's not that surprising that a word of very restricted syntax gave way to a nearly synonymous word without the restriction. I believe the same thing happened to Latin _inquit_.

Comment: Compare Ger [quatschen](https://dwds.de/wb/quatschen) "to chat, to speak, to utter" (pejorative in the sense "to speak" or paired with pejorative adverbs, aliterated in *Kacke quatschen* "to talk shit"; cf. *Quatsch* "nonsense"; cp. *quackeln* "to chat", *to quack*). Perhaps OE *cweath* "dung, shit", PGem \*kwēdaz "bad, evil" had created preasure for suppletion. Also, a few Christian influenced high literature texts are not enough to establish that the word was ever part of the *common* vernacular. *quote*, *Quittung*, *quittieren* all seem to stem from Latin.

Comment: Not to mention that there are many thematic synonyms of "to say". *schwatzen* hits the same vein as *quatschen*, and I just note it after trying to see the *velar* in "say" as a part of \*kweþana, for a \*\*(s)kweþana ... Kroonen does not pin-point a PIE root for \kwetana, suggests "\*g^w-et-e- (IE?)", seems to agree with "quatschen", and mentions many, many other comparisons deemed "difficult". PIE \*sek^w- "say" should have a labial, and has *-t-* in the slavic descendents, how about that?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First, just to note, **kweþaną* didn't completely die out: English "quoth" is archaic but still recognizable, and Icelandic *kveða* is still in active use.

But you're absolutely right about the general trend that killed off most descendants of **kweþaną*. It's now quite rare across the Germanic languages, when it used to be widespread. It's hard to say *why* something like this happens in linguistics, at least in a falsifiable way, but it's certainly possible to speculate and make some educated guesses.

As Colin Fine points out in the comments, there's a very nice parallel here with Latin *inquam*. *Inquam* ("I say") was a common Classical word with very restricted usage: it was always connected to a specific quotation or phrase of some sort, and almost always occurs in the present tense singular—it doesn't even have a single attestation of its infinitive, anywhere, in any stage of the language.

So despite its Classical popularity, *inquam* left no impression at all on modern Romance languages. It was simply too heavily restricted; more general words like *dicō* "to speak" took its place, giving French *dire*, Spanish *decir*, and so on.

It's entirely possible that the same thing happened with **kweþaną* in Germanic: the use of this verb became restricted to certain contexts, and eventually more general synonyms caught on and took its place. In the languages where the root survives, like Icelandic, it has no such restrictions (either having lost them or never developed them), and so it sticks around as a general-purpose verb for speech.

Comment: Thank you very much. Still I'm wondering how it may have come to the same substitution  in west-germanic and north-germanic languages.A sound conclusion might be that *sagjana may have been used frequently already in PrG and had no serious "concurrence" (eg. from *sprekana)